# Rails helpers causing input placeholder to not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some jQuery in my app that removes/shows a placeholder depending on the presence of input in the input field. Here it is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length) {
            $('label[for='+$(this).attr('name')+']').hide();
        } else {
            $('label[for='+$(this).attr('name')+']').show();
        }
    });
});
```

However this doesn't work due to my `label` and `text_field` form helpers. The HTML below is how the jQuery is set up to work:

```
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input id="user_email" name="user_email" size="38" type="text" />
```

Here's the HTML rendered using helpers:

```
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="38" type="text" />
```

As you can see, the helpers make it so the HTML for `label for` and `input id` don't match up with the HTML for `input name`. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: The label id and name look correct to me, based upon how Rails normally generates them.  Why not change your Jquery side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have special characters in attribute values (like `[` and `]`) then just enclose the value in quotation marks. I.e. instead of the selector `label[for=user[email]]` (which is broken) use `label[for="user[email]"]`. The equivalent change in your code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
      $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').hide();
    } else {
      $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. Not sure why, so what I may end up doing is have a `span` class that is the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this doesn't answer the rails question, but if you are considering using different code on the jQuery side:

I wrote a jQuery plugin for placeholders awhile back.  It does 3 color states on the text (placeholder blurred, placeholder focused, user input), custom placeholder text, as well as some mehods to be used for vaidation and form submission (i.e., is the placeholder active, or is it a user input).  It provides you with a CSS hook-in as well.  Maybe it could help?

**[Project Home](http://jyore.com/post/8/)**

Syntax wise you just attach it to a text field or a div and specify the placeholder text. Examples available in the docs.

Comment: Cool plugin. I'll check it out once I resolve the Rails issue!